# Record<string, any> to {name: string} in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a custom react hook to do a API calls:

```js
const useFetch: (string) => Record<string, any> | null = (path: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<string, any> | null>(null);

  var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "GET",
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  const fetcher = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT + path,
      requestOptions
    );
    const json = await res.json();
    setData(json.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher();
  }, [path]);
  return data;
};
```

My problem is that I use this hook to call many different endpoints, so I cannot specify the type for `data` in the hook. But when I call the hook, I know what the data is for that specific endpoint, so I want to specify a type for the variable storing the return value like:

```js
const data: { name: string } | null = useFetch('/example-end-point');
```

This is what I want to achieve, but I get this error: `Property 'name' is missing in type 'Record<string, any>' but required in type '{ name: string; }'.`

Using `any` for the return type works, but I don't want to resort to that if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Generic Types can solve, you can absolutely allow for variable types to be passed into your single hook with a little bit of a code re-write.

Take a look...

```
const useFetch: <T>(string) => Record<T> | null = (path: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<T> | null>(null);

  var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "GET",
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  const fetcher = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT + path,
      requestOptions
    );
    const json = await res.json();
    setData(json.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher();
  }, [path]);
  return data;
};
```

and then when you call it you can do the following.

```
type MyData = {
  name: string,
}
const data: MyData | null = useFetch<MyData>('/example-end-point');
```

Comment: it t seems you should replace `Record<string, T>` with just `T`

Comment: @Andrei not just can, but should: server responses are not necessarily object types.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use `unknown` instead of `any` then narrow down the type elsewhere by performing some type guarding ie

```js
const useFetch: (string) => unknown = (path: string) => {
...


const user = useFetch('/example-end-point')

if (!user || !user.name) throw new Error("Bad data")

const data: { name: string } = user
```

This way you get runtime data checking as well as type checking.